# How can i overload cin(>>) with vector of object

Tags: c++, class, vector, operator-overloading

If title wont make you understand issue .Here is the snippet of code with  what I'm trying to do with my code.
I have vector of class Book object and i want to take input for book object all at once so i thought to overload it . And during pushback operation it ask for class's >> version .So i made that but still i can't take input

```
class Book{
friend istream &operator>>(istream &in,Book &b);

    string name;
    unsigned int id;
    unsigned int no;

};
class Booklist{
    vector<Book>b;
    void addBook();
};
istream &operator>>(istream &in,Book &b)
{
   // cout<<"Enter book id , no and name :"<<endl; as suggested lets discard it but still its error prone
    cin>>b.id>>b.no>>b.name;
    return in;
}
void Booklist::addBook()
{
    int check;
    while(cin>>check){
        try{
            cout<<"Enter book serial number - "<<endl;
            cin>>b.push_back(); // Here is the error part
            if(cin){
                throw runtime_error("Input failed.\n");}
        }
        catch(runtime_error error){
            cout<<error.what()
                <<"Try again? Enter y or n.\n";
                char c;
                cin>>c;
                if(!cin || c=='n'){
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
}




***ERRORS IN COMPILER***

In member function 'void Booklist::addBook()':|
no matching function for call to 'std::vector<Book>::push_back()'|
note: candidate: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = Book; _Alloc = std::allocator<Book>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = Book]|
candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|
candidate: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = Book; _Alloc = std::allocator<Book>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = Book]|
note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|
```

Comment: please include the error message, it should have some good hints on what you are doing wrong

Comment: Your current `operator>>` function for `Book` have two major flaws: First it should not print any output, only read input. And secondly, it should read from the stream that is provided as the argument, not from `cin` (how else could you read from e.g. a file?).

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 yah lets do that.

Comment: btw using consistent intendation helps alot for readability

Comment: And instead of coding an `operator>>` function for `std::vector<Book>`, use [`std::istream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) to initialize the vector (or *any* suitable container). You can use the existing `Book` stream extract operator for that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i have corrected that use of << in cin overloadinf but its of no use .. still same issue .

Comment: You should include a `main` function so we can see how you're using that code. And provide some sample input. Because as it is now, getting this to work is a mystery. The first thing your `addBook` does is reading in `int check` without any prompt. The `if (cin) { throw [...]` part is very questionable (what do I have to input so it doesn't throw an exception here?) and the exception handling is puzzling, too. You ask if the user wants to try again, but the answer doesn't matter.

Comment: I think you need to take a couple of steps back, and reread about basic input/output, and how vectors and adding elements to vectors work. Because `cin >> b.push_back()` shows that you have some big misunderstandings.

Comment: If the parameter is `in`, why does the routine ignore it and instead use `cin`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basic misunderstanding here is that the function `push_back()` (note the empty parentheses) does not exist, and the compiler doesn't know what to do with it in conjunction with `cin >>`.

`push_back(Book b)` does exist, but you have to supply a temporary Book object, e.g. like so:

```
        Book book;
        cin >> book; // no more error
        b.push_back(book);
```